# MyBatis without Spring, transaction using provided connection

Tags: mybatis

I'm using MyBatis without Spring. I also must use a JDBC Connection provided by another API.

So I'm creating my SqlSession like this:

```
    Connection conn = //... provided by some API
    LOGGER.debug("Connection autocommit: " + conn.getAutoCommit()); // Autocommit is true by default
    conn.setAutoCommit(false); // So I set it to false first
    LOGGER.debug("Connection autocommit after: " + conn.getAutoCommit()); // It is now false
    return factory.openSession(conn);
```

Then in my code:

```
    try (SqlSession session = ...) {
        // Invoke mapper method here
        session.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        session.rollback();
        throw ex;
    }
```

However, I found that calling session.commit() does nothing (i.e. no log about the commit is found), and the changes are indeed not commited. It would seem MyBatis' commit() is being ignored for some reason.

If I don't force autocommit to be false, the changes will be committed (without having to call session.commit()), but I won't be able to rollback on errors either.

My SqlSessionFactory is created like this:

```
configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setDatabaseId(SQLSERVER_DATABASE_ID);                 
configuration.addMapper(ApprovalHierarchyMapper.class);     
factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
```

How do I implement programmatically controlled transaction, without Spring and with a provided JDBC connection?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it is because I didn't supply an Environment to SqlSessionFactory's cosnstructor that led to this weirdness. The Environment contains a reference to a TransactionManager.

So I tried adding Apache Commons Pool and DBCP and using a dummy BasicDataSource and JdbcTransactionManager to construct an Environment. However I found the code will really attempt to connect to the BasicDataSource, and I have no valid URL/login/password for it because I get my Connection from an API.

I then tried to call session.getConnection.commit()/rollback() instead of session.commit()/rollback(). That worked.

This is caused by me constructing the Configuration programmatically, which I have to because my program is a plugin of a software, and some data are only accessible in run-time when I get access to a plugin context.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and `session.commit()` worked as expected.

`SqlSessionFactory` is created as follows.

```java
Environment env = new Environment("development",
  new JdbcTransactionFactory(), new UnpooledDataSource());
Configuration config = new Configuration(env);
config.addMapper(YourMapper.class);
SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(config);
```

- `JdbcTransactionFactory` is used instead of the default `ManagedTransactionFactory`.
- `UnpooledDataSource` won't be used.

The part calling mapper methods looks the same as your example.

```java
con.setAutoCommit(false);
try (SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(con)) {
  YourMapper mapper = session.getMapper(YourMapper.class);
  // Invoke mapper methods here
  session.commit();
}
```

The transaction is rolled back when an exception is thrown.